# MySQL Optimization, my.cnf is almost empty

Tags: mysql, optimization

i have a virtual machine where i installed koha - Open Source Integrated Library System (ILS), it works ok but i want to optimizate mysql, i run MySQLTuner script and i got this recommendations:

```
General recommendations:
Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Performance should be activated for better diagnostics
Consider installing Sys schema from "Link"
Read this before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or 
innodb_log_files_in_group: "Link"
Variables to adjust:
query_cache_size (=0)
query_cache_type (=0)
performance_schema = ON enable PFS
innodb_log_file_size should be (=16M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files 
size equals to 25% of buffer pool size.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances (=1)
```

My current config in my my.cnf (/etc/mysql/my.cnf) file is:

```
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Does anyone have any recommendations about how to do those recommendations?

Comment: Please post the two 'included' files total text content so we can see what you are using for your configuration information at instance start.

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

Comment: The most important optimization is to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of _available_ RAM.  The rest of what mysqltuner says is less important.

Comment: Please post complete text report from MySQLTuner rather than just recommendations.  Valuable information will be in the report.